# Find the row of an index value in a Pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I import data and index it with the year (first column)

`rawData = pandas.read_csv(inFile)`

`rawData.set_index('Year', inplace=True)`

My data now has two columns, one of years, the other of prices,

Year     Price

1925     100

1926     105

1927     125

.

.

2014     1000

i now want to remove all data before a certain year, so i write

`startYr = 1946`

`rawData1 = rawData[startYr:]`

But this does nothing, because 1946 is greater than the largest index (which is 80). What's the right way in which to find the row startIdx that corresponds to 1946, so that i can then write

`startIdx = some_function(startYr)`

`rawData1 = rawData[startIdx:]`

Thanks in advance for your help

Thomas Philips

Answer (score 0):

Use [`loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#selection-by-label) for label based indexing:

```
In [3]:
df = pd.DataFrame(index = np.arange(1925,2015))
df

Out[3]:
Empty DataFrame
Columns: []
Index: [1925, 1926, 1927, 1928, 1929, 1930, 1931, 1932, 1933, 1934, 1935, 1936, 1937, 1938, 1939, 1940, 1941, 1942, 1943, 1944, 1945, 1946, 1947, 1948, 1949, 1950, 1951, 1952, 1953, 1954, 1955, 1956, 1957, 1958, 1959, 1960, 1961, 1962, 1963, 1964, 1965, 1966, 1967, 1968, 1969, 1970, 1971, 1972, 1973, 1974, 1975, 1976, 1977, 1978, 1979, 1980, 1981, 1982, 1983, 1984, 1985, 1986, 1987, 1988, 1989, 1990, 1991, 1992, 1993, 1994, 1995, 1996, 1997, 1998, 1999, 2000, 2001, 2002, 2003, 2004, 2005, 2006, 2007, 2008, 2009, 2010, 2011, 2012, 2013, 2014]

[90 rows x 0 columns]

In [5]:
df.loc[1946:]

Out[5]:
Empty DataFrame
Columns: []
Index: [1946, 1947, 1948, 1949, 1950, 1951, 1952, 1953, 1954, 1955, 1956, 1957, 1958, 1959, 1960, 1961, 1962, 1963, 1964, 1965, 1966, 1967, 1968, 1969, 1970, 1971, 1972, 1973, 1974, 1975, 1976, 1977, 1978, 1979, 1980, 1981, 1982, 1983, 1984, 1985, 1986, 1987, 1988, 1989, 1990, 1991, 1992, 1993, 1994, 1995, 1996, 1997, 1998, 1999, 2000, 2001, 2002, 2003, 2004, 2005, 2006, 2007, 2008, 2009, 2010, 2011, 2012, 2013, 2014]

[69 rows x 0 columns]
```

What you tried:

```
In [6]:
df[1946:]

Out[6]:
Empty DataFrame
Columns: []
Index: []
```

won't work as this looks for a column named `1946`

So to specifically look for rows after `1946` you have to use `1947`, this assumes that `1947` does exist in your index:

```
df.loc[1947:]
```

Comment: Perfect! Thanks a mill for the quick response